# Reading secure cookies in android WebView

Tags: android, webview, session-cookies

I am working on a android web application and based on if a secure cookie exists I want to do something. Unfortunately when I use the following line of code I only get a list of unsecure cookies.

```
String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName)
```

Does anyone know how I can get a list of all secure cookies for a specific domain?

Answer (score 9):

You can retrieve secure cookies by using a url that starts with "https://".

```
String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie("https://example.com");
```

Returns all cookies (including secure only ones). Logic for getting cookies can be read at: https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/master/net/cookies/cookie_monster.cc#L1780 .

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I added the following before I created the webView

CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);

see [CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(boolean accept)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(boolean))

Comment: I have some secure cookies as well, but calling the method mentioned, will not add the secure cookies when retrieving them via CookieManager's getCookie method. Do you have any clue on that?

Comment: The above answer will not work btw, the FileSchemeCookies are not related to secure cookies.